# Rails won't recognise keys after renaming model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I just renamed my table **Client** to **Person** using this command:

```
class RenameClientsToPeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_table :clients, :people
  end
end
```

Then I carefully renamed all instances, filenames and foreign keys (thanks to Veraticus) from *client* to *person* and from *clients* to *people*. But for some reason I still get errors like this:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: people.person_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "projects" INNER JOIN "people" ON "projects"."person_id" = "people"."person_id" WHERE "people"."user_id" = 1
```

Why won't Rails recognise the new primary key?

Comment: why you renamed everything, that is the foolish thing you did, you could have added a line in model, use table persons.

Comment: put your ruby code for this query and code for people model.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh: I disagree, adding your "one line" would just kick the can into the future and keep causing problems.

Comment: @Tintin81, yes if it is the case of future maintainablity then you are right.

Comment: You're apparently using a non-standard PK: `person_id` vice `id`.  Is that expected?  I assume `user_id` is a FK for People?  Does your `schema.rb` file contain a column with this name?  Does this query work in the console?

Comment: No, *user_id* belongs to the user that *has_many* people. I just created a user and a person on the console. The user automatically gets his ID set upon creation, the person doesn't! It simply get an ID of 'nil'. My schema and all the migrations have been carefully updated before.

Comment: Ahhh, solved now. I had a stupid *set_primary_key "person_id"* in my Person model which I had forgotten to remove. Shame on me! Thanks for your help guys.